# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando pase el cursor encima del botón se mueva sin hacer click en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quiero hacer que con solo pasar el cursor se mueva el botón ahí lo estoy haciendo con la biblioteca random pero quiero que se mueva sin oprimirlo y si lo llegan oprimir que ponga winner

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def move_button():
    pass

def press_button():
    messagebox.showinfo("titulo", "ganaste")

root = Tk()
root.title("Game")
root.geometry("200x200")

Button(root, text ="Press me",command = press_button).place(x = 70,y = 20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código como texto por favor? Así puedo hacer pruebas sin tener que transcribir el código.

Comment: import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def move_button():
    pass
def press_button():
    messagebox.showinfo("titulo", "ganaste")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Game")
root.geometry("200x200")


button = tk.Button(root, text ="Press me",command = press_button)
button.place(x = 70,y = 20)

Comment: Gracias por el código, pero en los comentarios no se formatea bien. Podrías editar tu pregunta, pegarlo allí y darle formato por favor? Puedes darle formato seleccionandolo todo y presionando las {} arriba de la caja de texto.

Comment: aaaaa okey una disculpa soy nuevo en esta plataforma

Comment: No te preocupes, todos hemos sido nuevos en algo alguna vez ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junté el código que muestras en tu imagen con el que pegaste:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint

def move_button(evento):
    evento.widget.place(x = randint(0, 100), y = randint(0,100))

def press_button():
    messagebox.showinfo("titulo", "ganaste")

root = Tk()
root.title("Game")
root.geometry("200x200")

btn = Button(root, text ="Press me",command = press_button)
btn.place(x = 70,y = 20)
btn.bind("<Enter>", move_button)

root.mainloop()
```

Acá te explico las principales diferencias:

```
def move_button(evento):
```

Ponemos el argumento `evento` porque queremos hacer los cambios sobre el botón, que he separado como una variable, y más adelante se lo vamos a enviar a la función move_button:

```
btn.bind("<Enter>", move_button)
```

Así de simple funciona. [`bind` en tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) sirve para indicar qué acciones va a hacer tu programa cuando ocurra un evento, en este caso  (el primer argumento, que indica que el mouse ha entrado en el espacio del widget), que es el evento que se dispara cuando el mouse entra en el espacio de un widget. El segundo argumento es, entonces, la función. `bind()` siempre va a mandar el evento ocurrido como argumento, y luego podemos agarrar el widget (el botón) al que corresponde este evento con `evento.widget`.

Comment: También puedes acceder al widget que generó el evento con x.widget. De cualquier modo, cabe aclarar que el evento que usas NO se activa cuando un cursor pasa por encima del widget, si no cuando **entra** al widget.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Gracias Dante, tienes razón. Le saco el lambda innecesario. En lo segundo también tienes razón, vale aclarar que <Enter> es solo cuando entra, también hay uno de <Leave> cuando el mouse sale del widget, me parece que no hay uno específico para determinar que el mouse esté encima.